# Filter with multiple conditions in R dataset

Tags: r

Data:

```r
dataset = data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                     date = c(120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 
                              120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 
                              120123, 120123, 120123),
                     section = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                 "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                     score = c(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0))
```

I need to filter out the whole group in case the score of "a" is >= the score of "b". Expected result:

```r
   date   group section score
1  120123     1       a     0
2  120123     1       b     3
3  120123     1       c     0
4  120123     1       d     0
5  120123     1       e     0
6  120123     3       a     0
7  120123     3       b     3
8  120123     3       c     1
9  120123     3       d     2
10 120123     3       e     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::filter` with argument `.by` to specify the grouping column.

```r
> library(dplyr)
> dataset |>
+     filter(!(score[section == "a"] >= score[section == "b"]), .by = group) 
   group   date section score
1      1 120123       a     0
2      1 120123       b     3
3      1 120123       c     0
4      1 120123       d     0
5      1 120123       e     0
6      3 120123       a     0
7      3 120123       b     3
8      3 120123       c     1
9      3 120123       d     2
10     3 120123       e     0
```

or `by` (base R)

```r
with(dataset, 
     by(dataset, group, \(x) x[x$score[x$section == "a"] < x$score[x$section == "b"], ])) |> 
  do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
  `row.names<-`(NULL) #cosmetics
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ave

```
tmp1=ave(dataset$score*(dataset$section=="a"),dataset$group,FUN=max)
tmp2=ave(dataset$score*(dataset$section=="b"),dataset$group,FUN=max)
dataset[tmp1<tmp2,]

   group   date section score
1      1 120123       a     0
2      1 120123       b     3
3      1 120123       c     0
4      1 120123       d     0
5      1 120123       e     0
11     3 120123       a     0
12     3 120123       b     3
13     3 120123       c     1
14     3 120123       d     2
15     3 120123       e     0
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` is your frend here. you can write a custom function to achieve that like this:

```
library(dplyr)

group_filter <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    group_by(date, group) %>%
    filter(!(score[section == "a"] >= score[section == "b"])) %>%
    ungroup()
}

# Your dataset
group <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
date <- c(120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123, 120123)
section <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
score <- c(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0)

dataset <- data.frame(date, group, section, score)

# Applying the filter function
result <- group_filter(dataset)

result
# A tibble: 10 × 4
     date group section score
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 120123     1 a           0
 2 120123     1 b           3
 3 120123     1 c           0
 4 120123     1 d           0
 5 120123     1 e           0
 6 120123     3 a           0
 7 120123     3 b           3
 8 120123     3 c           1
 9 120123     3 d           2
10 120123     3 e           0
```